# typescript: Class returns empty object

Tags: typescript

I got this Typescript Class im trying to get tor work but for some reason it just wont give me the correct class instance after I've instanciated it

**Class GamesService**

```
export interface IGame {
  name: string;
  online: number;
  likes: number;
  playedCount: number;
  images: {
    small: string;
    medium: string;
    large: string;
  }
}

export class GamesService {
  public getGames(): IGame[] {
    return []
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
private getGames(): IGame[] {
 const GS = new GamesService();

 console.log(GS);

 return [];
}
```

the console.log returns the following out put: `GamesService {}` i would expect `GamesService {getGames: f()}`

Can some one help me here, im quite new to typescript :)

Comment: It's OK but the method is in the prototype. Just try to call the method, it'll work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript transpiles your code to a javascript like this -

```
var GamesService = (function () {
    function GamesService() {
    }
    GamesService.prototype.getGames = function () {
        return [];
    };
    return GamesService;
}());
var GS = new GamesService();
console.log(GS);
```

It outputs like this -
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The object is correct and it works. What you are seeing is just console.log() output behavior. You can try calling methods of GS to confirm.

Comment: Thanks for some reason i must have failed for me earlier :)